# @api validate of Salesforce flow lets user continue to next screen even when the isValid property is set to false

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I want to control to users navigation to the next screen. If the all the fields are not filled in and when the user clicks on next button the shouldn't proceed to next screen.
I have two input fields which is an LWC component and the other two being normal flow components.
I am able to check if the flow components are filled in when pressing the next button, but not eh controls I have in the lwc component
Here are my two controls -

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectName} >
        <lightning-input-field class="field1" value={field1Value} required message-when-value-missing="This field is required!" onchange={handleFirstFieldChange} ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field class="field2" value={field2Value} required message-when-value-missing="This field is required!" onchange={handleSecondFieldChange} ></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>

    @api 
    validate() {
        let customErrors = [];
        let field1= this.template.querySelector(".field1");
        let field1Value = field1.value;

        let field2= this.template.querySelector(".field2");
        let field2Value= field2.value;


        if (!field1Value && !field2Value) {

            return { isValid: false };
            //user shouldn't navigate to next screen when pressing the flow next button
        }
    }
```

According to the documentation here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_flow_validate_user_input_for_custom_components,

I believe isValid is the property that triggers the navigation.

What would I be doing wrong here?

Comment: have you added a `console.log` within your `validate()` method to confirm it's returning `false` or to confirm what's the value of `field1` and `field2`

Comment: Coulcn't continue with this, had to go forward with another method, have to look into in the future.